# Best way to handle images in Java

Tags: java, image

I will develop a Java application that uses some image processing algorithms. I have done some image processing applications using C++. I'm currently using BufferedImage object to save data from images but I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle images in Java (improve performance).

Do you guys have any recommendation?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You could always use your C++ libraries in Java if you are happy with them. This would require use of JNI which shouldn't be too much of a problem for you if you already know C/C++.

Comment: Do **not** perform premature optimization.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to work with images i would look at JavaCv: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

> JavaCV first provides wrappers to commonly used libraries by researchers in the field of computer vision: OpenCV, FFmpeg, libdc1394, PGR FlyCapture, OpenKinect, videoInput, and ARToolKitPlus.

I think you will find all what you need.

Luca

Answer (score 1):

For JAVA there exists for example:
FiJi

- [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/)
- [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Fiji)
- [BoofCV](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [Rapidminer with IMMI](http://spl.utko.feec.vutbr.cz/en/component/content/article/46-image-processing-extension-for-rapidminer-5) (for image mining)